# OpenLayers and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I was wondering if anybody knows if there are any existing TypeScript definition files for OpenLayers (or if they are already in the making).

I tried parsing the OpenLayers source files myself and use the documentation comments to build a TypeScript definition file but to really make this work I would need a complete JavaScript parser that also understand the documentation syntax in OpenLayers (it uses NaturalDocs, http://naturaldocs.org) and I'm beginning to think that translating the info by hand is easier than writing such a parser :(.

So does anybody now of a similar project or has an idea how to accomplish the task of generating those TypeScript definition files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For OL2 see here: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/openlayers/openlayers.d.ts

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any mention of an OpenLayers.d.ts file yet but there's a growing list of definition files being tracked over [here](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/398150).

Comment: See Rui Lima's answer below.  It takes a 10 minutes of tweaking to get working in VS2013 w/ TS 1.4 and AMD.  Worth the effort!

Answer (score 1):

Today I have uploaded the definitions for OL 3.1.1 to Github:
https://github.com/3x0dv5/ol3-typescript-definitions
Feel free to use

Comment: I get a large number of errors with these related to invalid enums in the closure-compiler definitions, mochikit isn't there.

Comment: what's the version of OL you're using. did you do submodule update?

Comment: +//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.3.0  
+I did the git submodule update --init as instructed  
+The errors are in the definitions themselves (the closure definitions)  
+I am using VS2013 w/ TS 1.4

Comment: +I pulled those files again and some of the the 21 errors related to goog.fx is not being defined.  +The content of goog/fx.d.ts is empty apart from /// <reference path="../../../globals.d.ts" />  +one reference was in ol.control.d.ts.

Comment: +Adding a reference to fx/dragger.d.ts resolves that error and then I get a couple hundred errors with, "An enum member cannot have a numeric name." +field.d.ts contains `enum SELECTION_CHANGE_KEYCODES_ { 8, 9, 13, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46 } `

Comment: after a short amount of time I was able to get everything working.  I had to delete some invalid enums, exclude Angular and add some explicit closure definition references to a few of your files and now I get code-assist for OL3!

Comment: I'm sorry, haven't had the time to update to the new openlayers version. Still 3.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definition file yet.  I also thought about creating one but instead just resorted to using it via ambient variable declaration.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on your solution? Or maybe even share the "definition" parts with the community?

Comment: @chrischu, I have not yet found time to create a definitions file and so there are no definition parts to share with the community.  Will like to do this but need to find some spare time  To use OpenLayers,  I did nothing special but use it as just another regular library without a TypeScript definition file.  In my TypeScript module definition I have this:    declare var OpenLayers;

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to TypeScript definition files for Openlayers.

[OpenLayers Definitionfiles](https://www.github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/openlayers)

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but have you looked into closurets?
https://github.com/teppeis/closure-ts
It seems promising, however, I wasn't able to convert any ol3 js files. I will try to dig a bit deeper and let you know.