# typescript definitions for openLayers

Tags: typescript, openlayers

Here's a function I need to use in typescript code:

```
ol.inherits(child, parent);
```

How to add a definition for that function in OpenLayers.d.ts file?

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/openlayers/openlayers.d.ts

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: For OL3 see here: https://github.com/3x0dv5/ol3-typescript-definitions/tree/master/ol3 and this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785670/openlayers-and-typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested sample but a likely candidate:

```
declare module OpenLayers {
    export function inherits(child:any,base:any);
}
```

A Pull Request + test would be welcome if you manage to use this function.

## PS:

I recommend using the `extends` keyword and not bothering with the `inherits` function as it will give you better type safety. For example

```
class FooLayer extends OpenLayers.Layer{
}
```